# help showing the uniform continuity function F

Tags: real-analysis

If $\lambda$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^k$ and $F:\lambda \rightarrow \mathbb R^d$ and if $\{a_n\} \; and \; \{b_n\}$ are sequences in $\lambda$ where $||a_n-b_n||\rightarrow 0$ then $||F(a_n)-F(b_n)||\rightarrow 0$ $\implies F$ is uniform continuous.

Dilemma:
I know the definition of uniform continuity is that for $\epsilon \exists \delta$ so that $||F(x)-F(y)||<\epsilon$ whenever $||x-y||<\delta$ so do I need show that $a_n \rightarrow a$ etc?  How to solve such a problem as this

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need any assumption on the limits of the sequence. Uniform continuity is a property of differences being small.

Comment: Hmm...maybe post this as a comment?